# How can I slightly adjust the number of tickmarks in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm drawing a time series chart with JFreeChart. The automated tickmark generation algorithm seems good; however it delivers more tickmarks than I want - about 15, where I really want 5-10.

Is there a way I can adjust the number of tickmarks that the standard algorithm generates? I don't want to have to explicitly set each tickmark, and the number of tickmarks doesn't have to exactly match the number I specify - more of a hint than a specific number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the API to provide such a hint, the `NumberAxis` class just tries to select a standard tick size that shows the largest number of tick marks without any of the labels overlapping.  You could modify that behaviour by overriding the `selectAutoTickUnit()` method in the `NumberAxis` class.

If you don't want to modify the code, you could encourage less ticks to be displayed by increasing the insets for the tick labels with the `setTickLabelInsets(RectangleInsets insets)` method.

Comment: setTickLabelInsets does what I need. Fundamentally it's the sparser spacing that I need.